# Rest Assured: How do I return JSON response as a String? (Java)

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How will I return a JSON response as a String with my code?

**Purpose** : I want to call `getAccessToken()` after it has obtained the accessToken from a json response body and need to return it as a `String` to be used in other methods.

The response example I'm trying to obtain:

```
"accessToken" : "The ID I need from here"
```

Code :

```
private String apiAccessToken;

public JsonPath getAccessToken() {
    JsonPath jsonPath = given().header("X-API-KEY", Config.API_KEY).header("session", this.sessionID)
            .header("username", this.userNameId).queryParam("code", verifiedCode).log().all()
            .get(baseUri + basePath + "/vm1/verifyCode").then().log().all().extract().jsonPath();

    this.apiAccessToken = jsonPath.get("accessToken");
    return new JsonPath(apiAccessToken);
}
```

[*Added - Showing how I'm using solutions from comments below*]

Example of how I call this method

```
public static String getToken(String key) {
    String res = given()
            .header("X-API-KEY", Config.API_KEY)
            .header("session", this.SessionId)
            .header("username", this.UserName)
            .queryParam("code", verifiedCode)
            .log().all()
            .get(baseUri + basePath + "/vm1 /verifyCode")
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .extract().asString();

    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res);
    return js.get(key).toString();
}

public static String getJsonPath(Response response, String key) {
    String complete = response.asString();
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(complete);
    return js.get(key).toString();
}

@Test
    public void testAuthValidator() throws InterruptedException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String sentCode = GmailUtility.getVerificationCode(); // Uses GMAIL API service to to read and get code from email and sends to getAccessToken
        System.out.println(sentCode);
        String Token = getToken("accessToken"); // Validates verification code. Spits out response for accessToken
        System.out.println(validator);
        driver = initializeDriver(); // Invokes Chrome
        driver.get(env.API_Website); // Goes to api website
        AuthApi auth = new AuthApi(driver);
        auth.getAuthorizeButton().click(); // Clicks a text field on webpage
        auth.getValueField().sendKeys("Token " + Token); // Need to call extracted response for the accessToken from getAccessToken.
```

Comment: Please refer this; [Extracting values from the Response after validation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#extracting-values-from-the-response-after-validation)

Comment: @kaweesha - Thank you for the resource. Rest Assured seems to have alot of syntactic sugar and just so much to learn. Much appreciated as always. Bookmarked this link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just write a simple reusable method to extract values using JSONPath and call the method in your code, here's a sample

**Reusable Method :**

```
public static String getJsonPath(Response response, String key) {
    String complete = response.asString();
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(complete);
    return js.get(key).toString();
}
```

**Test :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Response res = given().header("X-API-KEY", Config.API_KEY).header("session", this.sessionID)
            .header("username", this.userNameId).queryParam("code", verifiedCode).log().all()
            .get(baseUri + basePath + "/vm1/verifyCode").then().log().all().extract().response();
    String value = getJsonPath(res, "accessToken");
    
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Update :

```
public static String getToken(String key) {
    String res = given().header("X-API-KEY", Config.API_KEY).header("session", this.SessionId)
            .header("username", this.UserName).queryParam("code", verifiedCode).log().all()
            .get(baseUri + basePath + "/vm1 /verifyCode").then().log().all().extract().asString();
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res);
    return js.get(key).toString();
}

@Test
public void testAuthValidator() throws InterruptedException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String sentCode = GmailUtility.getVerificationCode();
    System.out.println(sentCode);
    String Token = getToken("accessToken");
    System.out.println(Token);
    driver = initializeDriver();
    driver.get(env.API_Website);
    AuthApi auth = new AuthApi(driver);
    auth.getAuthorizeButton().click();
    auth.getValueField().sendKeys("Token " + Token);
}
```

You can get any value using this

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added your solution to a scenario I'm working on(left comments within code) to show the code flow. I'm not exactly sure how to apply what you provided to `auth.getValueField().sendKeys("Token " + **NEED ACCESS TOKEN AS STRING**);`. Can you please provide additional guidance?

Comment: Check the updated section, Also delete the getAccessToken() from your code and use the code I have given

Comment: Ah I see. To my understanding, the `getToken` parameter is set to `String`.  `extract().asString()` is used and we then return the extracted response as a String. Cool. One thing I'm noticing. The re-usable method you provided is not being called for some reason, I have updated my example code for observation, please let me know if anything looks off.

Comment: Would you be able to dial into my webex ?

Comment: Sure, let me see how to do that.

Comment: The solution you have provided is working as expected. Thank you for your guidance on this.